# Explanation of ThreadLocal leaks for custom ThreadLocal classes

Tags: java, tomcat, thread-local

I have been reading this [article](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection#customThreadLocal) on ThreadLocal leaks in Tomcat. The first example includes this code:

```
public class MyCounter {
        private int count = 0;

        public void increment() {
                count++;
        }

        public int getCount() {
                return count;
        }
}

public class MyThreadLocal extends ThreadLocal<MyCounter> {
}

public class LeakingServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static MyThreadLocal myThreadLocal = new MyThreadLocal();

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

                MyCounter counter = myThreadLocal.get();
                if (counter == null) {
                        counter = new MyCounter();
                        myThreadLocal.set(counter);
                }

                response.getWriter().println(
                                "The current thread served this servlet " + counter.getCount()
                                                + " times");
                counter.increment();
        }
}
```

It says that all of the classes reside in the webapp. It then outlines the following explanation for the classloader (not ThreadLocal) leak, which I don't understand:

> If the LeakingServlet is invoked at least once and the Thread that
>   served it is not stopped, then we created a classloader leak !
>
> The leak is caused because we have a custom class for the ThreadLocal
>   instance, and also a custom class for the value bound to the Thread.
>   Actually the important thing is that both classes were loaded by the
>   webapp classloader.

The explanation for the ThreadLocal leak is terrible. How do we have a ThreadLocal leak (actually the article says classloader leak) if the Thread which served the request is not stopped? Does this mean, if the Thread is part of a Tomcat thread pool and since `MyThreadLocal.remove()` has not been closed, then the webapp classloader for MyCounter / MyThreadLocal cannot be garbage collected since the Thread is returned to the pool? Would calling `MyThreadLocal.remove()` fix this? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation is not correct:

> The leak is caused because we have a custom class for the ThreadLocal instance

That part is wrong. ThreadLocalMap in Thread class uses weakReferences for keys so it does not matter if threadLocal instance is a custom class. I tested that with my custom ThreadLocal class and there are no memory leaks.

> , and also a custom class for the value bound to the Thread.

This is correct. For values thread does not use weak references so if a value is a custom class that will prevent it's class loader to be garbage collected which will cause all classes loaded by that class loader to stay in memory until thread is removed from thread pool.

Comment: But when would you call that? It would only clean ThreadLocal from current thread. It is better to use AtomicLong instead of a custom class and then you will not have class loader leaks because AtomicLong is loaded by bootstrap class loader instead of the same class loader that loaded your app.

Comment: Another solution is to use ImprovedThreadLocal that I created. Find it on github.